# How to fix "fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory" to build Darknet properly with conda virtual environment

Tags: opencv, anaconda, darknet

I am using conda virtual environment on Ubuntu 20.04 and I got this error while using "make" in Darknet folder even if my virtual environment(conda) has Opencv installed.

Here is the screenshot of the error:

[image: Here is the screenshot of the error]

Here is that cv2 is working and its version(4.5.5):

[image: Here is that cv2 is working and its version(4.5.5)]

Here is the environment variables for CUDA and Opencv I used (in .bashrc):

[image: Here is the environment variables for CUDA and Opencv I used (in .bashrc)]

Thanks in advance for your any help!

Comment: please review [ask] and [mre]. no screenshots of text. copy the text into your question.

Comment: installing a *python* package will not give you any of the required files to use OpenCV from C++

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz So, do I need to install OpenCV package in official OpenCV documentation [link](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) and build it to use it properly for my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is originated from not building OpenCV as Darknet needs.

As @ChristophRackwitz implied, showing python version worked is not enough to build darknet with OpenCV capability. To be able to build darknet with OpenCV ON, OpenCV should be built with C++ functionalities as some of instructions might be followed:

[Instruction 1](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu-20-04/)

[Instruction 2](https://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/ece480/capstone/fall13/group04/docs/jerapp.pdf)
and so on.